# Response.Redirect not redirecting to a specific URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect to some page after login.

Here is my code

```
ViewBag.userid = Session[Declaration.sUserID];
var userid = ViewBag.userid;
if (userid == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("signin?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri));
}
else
{
    string ReturnUrl = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["url"]);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
    {
        Response.Redirect(ReturnUrl);//http://localhost:55197/usermanagement
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("DashBoard");
    }
}
return View();
```

The problem is that it is not redirecting from `Response.Redirect` part and always calls the same view again and gain.

Someone have an idea why it's happening?

Comment: `Response.Redirect` should be replaced with`return Redirect`

Comment: Better to *never* use `Response.Redirect()` in MVC, it is an ASP.NET (Web Forms) construct that does not work well with MVC. The accepted answer below gives the solution, but I'd like to emphasize that the two methods work very differently despite their similar names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "return" once you call Response.Redirect, otherwise the code will continue and eventually call return View(), which returns the original view back to the caller. e.g.

```
ViewBag.userid = Session[Declaration.sUserID];

    var userid = ViewBag.userid;
    if (userid == null)
    {
        return Redirect("signin?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri));
    }
    else
    {
        string ReturnUrl = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["url"]);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);//http://localhost:55197/usermanagement
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("DashBoard");
        }
    }


    return View();
```

Comment: what to write in a return statement

Comment: Apologies. I rushed that answer!! Change it from Response.Redirect to "return Redirect(...)". I've updated the answer to show this